# Opacity Style doesn't work in a call back Java Script?

Tags: javascript, html, opacity

The loop is working ok after callback of assigned eventlistener function fade() but console show me that opacity doesn't modify when the value is changing. What i'm doing wrong?

```
function fade(element) {

    var easeIn = 0.01;
    var easeOut = 0.01;

    for (alpha = 1; alpha >= 0.2 ; alpha -= easeIn){
        element.target.style.opacity = String(alpha);
        console.log(alpha, element.target);
    }

    for (alpha = 0.2; alpha <= 1 ; alpha += easeOut){
        element.target.style.opacity = alpha;
        console.log(alpha, element.target);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop runs synchronously, and the browser *batches* style changes - the display will only update once all Javascript has completed, and by that time, the opacity will be back to 1, so visually, there won't appear to have been any changes.

Add a small delay inside the loops instead:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
async function fade(element) {

    var easeIn = 0.01;
    var easeOut = 0.01;

    for (alpha = 1; alpha >= 0.2 ; alpha -= easeIn){
        element.style.opacity = String(alpha);
        await delay(20);
    }

    for (alpha = 0.2; alpha <= 1 ; alpha += easeOut){
        element.style.opacity = alpha;
        await delay(20);
    }    
}

const elm = document.querySelector('button');
elm.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fade(elm);
});
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

(note that a variable named `element` should probably *actually be an element*, else you may well cause confusion for others who read the code, including you later)

For multiple buttons, make sure you declare the `alpha` variable, else it'll be implicitly global and shared by all listeners:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
async function fade(element) {
    var easeIn = 0.01;
    var easeOut = 0.01;

    for (let alpha = 1; alpha >= 0.2 ; alpha -= easeIn){
        element.style.opacity = String(alpha);
        await delay(20);
    }

    for (let alpha = 0.2; alpha <= 1 ; alpha += easeOut){
        element.style.opacity = alpha;
        await delay(20);
    }    
}

for (const elm of document.querySelectorAll('button')) {
  elm.addEventListener('click', () => {
    fade(elm);
  });
}
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Clear as water, and thanks for your advice about the naming. Is there any possibility of avoiding the delay? My intention is for the two loops to start and end 100% regardless of any other events.

Comment: A visual delay in fadeout/fadein (regardless of whether caused by JS or CSS) is absolutely necessary, otherwise the user won't see the fade effect.

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much for your help. I think you would need to create an object for each event that occurs within the document because they interrupt each other so that the fade in and the fade out do not work independently of the others that are created. Perhaps generating a class and creating an object for each event would be convenient?

Comment: The problem is that `alpha` is implicitly global. Consider using strict mode to avoid these sorts of problem - always declare variables before you use them. Scope `alpha` to inside the loop or function block, so it's not shared between calls, and it'll work fine, see snippet

Comment: you are awesome.